# how to select max value integer from varchar column using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data from char column. how to select max int from char column.
in this case, i want to select max from the red line in the picture

[image]

i want 02 as the max value.

i tried this:

```
select MAX(RIGHT(kode_akun,5)) as kode from tbl_akun WHERE LEFT(kode_akun,9)='1.1.03.01'
```

but i got 02.00 .

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: sorry, I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query is right.

```
Declare @tbl Table(
id INT ,
[group]  Varchar(50),
value varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'1.1.03.01.00.00',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(2,'1.1.03.01.01.00',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(3,'1.1.03.01.02.00',NULL)

Select MAX(RIGHT([group],5)) as kode from @tbl WHERE LEFT([group],9)='1.1.03.01'
```

In this table got max value 2.0

Comment: solved!
with this query : `select MAX(SUBSTR(kode_akun,11,2)) as kode from tbl_akun WHERE LEFT(kode_akun,9)='1.1.03.01' `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(substring_index(substring_index(kode_akun, '.', -2), '.', -1) + 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written is correct just get first 2 digit of 02.00 by using `LEFT()` function on `RIGHT(kode_akun,5)`

```
select MAX(LEFT(RIGHT(kode_akun,5),2)) as kode from tbl_akun WHERE LEFT(kode_akun,9)='1.1.03.01'  group by LEFT(IP,9)
```